# What is the Pasifika response to "Nation"?

Tags: terry-pratchett, reception, nation

Pratchett's *Nation* was recommended to me because it depicts an alternate reality version of Pasifika cultures, faiths, and traditions. A quick glance at Wikipedia tells me it's got cannibals and reveals that a Pasifika culture is the forgotten remnant of a culture which was once successful by Western standards of science and technology. My Googles, however, have not turned up much information on what kind of reception this book got from Pasifika people.

How was *Nation* received by Pasifika audiences? What's the general popular and critical response to it by Pasifika voices?

Comment: Note that IIRC most substantiated information that we get about the Raiders (Wikipedia’s cannibals) is that they are, well, raiders. They are demonised by everybody else in many respects (little surprisingly) and I read the cannibalism to be part of this. Of course, they may really be cannibals, but they never eat anybody on-page and given the killing and pillaging, cannibalism is not their most objectionable feature.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft The same is true of the original Cannibals as well.